# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with uint64_t

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm getting segmentation fault with my following code. This is the max size in which I get no segmentation error `SIZE = 1000000` if I increase it one zero more, I got segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t SIZE = 10000000;

uint64_t getsum(int data[], uint64_t size)
{
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    uint64_t i = 0;

    for ( i; i < size; ++i)
        sum += data[i];

    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int data[SIZE];
    uint64_t i = 0;

    for ( i; i < SIZE; ++i)
        data[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    printf("sum: %"PRIu64" \n", getsum(data, SIZE));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) - `data` is too large for the stack - either allocate it dynamically or make it `static`.

Comment: Local variables are usually stored on the stack of the process, and each process stack is limited, usually in the single-digit megabyte range. For example, on Windows it's usually only a single megabyte. Your array `data` is *way* larger than a megabyte, and way larger than the 8MB default stack on Linux.

Comment: Is there a way to know the size of stack?

Comment: @CroCo use this command `ulimit -a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exceeding the available stack space, therefore causing a segfault. If the `data` array is so big, it shouldn't be with automatic storage.

You should either define it `static`, globally, or allocate it on the heap.